# How to get html table focused row specific column data on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I want get specific column value based on **keypress** event. I given keypress event for recovery cost column. based on recovery cost entry I have to fetch standard rate and compare the values. if recovery cost greater than standard rate then show one alert message.

[image]

**Function:**

```
<td> 
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtStdRate" value='<%# Eval("std_rt")%>'/></td>                                             
<td>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtRcvryCost" value='<%# Eval("recovery_cost")%>'onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/>
 </td> 


**......................**

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
           var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
           if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
           && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
              return false;

           return true;
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the validation you have to add onKeyUp:
try following:

```
    <td>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="Text3" value='<%# Eval("std_rt")%>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="Text4" value='<%# Eval("recovery_cost")%>'
            onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onkeyup="checkWithStdrate(event);" />
    </td>
```

Then Write following Function:

```
    function checkWithStdrate(evt) {
        var prevTextBox = parseInt($(evt.target).parent().prev().find("input").val());
        var thisTextBox = parseInt($(evt.target).val());

        if (thisTextBox > prevTextBox) {
            alert("Error Message");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this is working for the adjacent columns. I want to compare the 5th column with 7th column. Please check the image I posted with above question. So how can I change "parseInt($(evt.target).parent().prev().find("input").val());"

Comment: You can add prev() to step one column left, or next() to step one column right. 
Example: Following will compare this column value with the column that is three columns left to this column- 
parseInt($(evt.target).parent().prev().prev().prev().find("input").val())